# HTML entities getting inserted into my Node.js script

Tags: html, node.js, phpstorm

I have a Node.js script I'm trying to write, and I keep getting this error: `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. Here is the full error:

```
file:///home/username/www/pathtomyapp/js/folder/file.js:1
console.log('working')&#10
                       ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:468:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:68:21)

Node.js v18.15.0
```

The content of `file.js` is this: `console.log('working')` there is no ampersand in my script. I'm using PhpStorm.

I had to look it up and it looks like an HTML entity, which does not make sense to me. I'm forking file.js, here is my code:

```js
 let child = fork('./folder/file.js')
```

What is creating HTML entities in my `file.js` and making it syntax-invalid? The ampersand does not show up in PhpStorm, it's only when I try to run the file. I'm running Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: try adding a semicolon (;) + line break. &#10 could be a LF (ASCII code 10 for line feed) on the end of the file

Comment: 1) Please **always** state your IDE version and OS used. 2) Please disable all **custom** (not bundled by default) plugins, restart the IDE and try again -- any better? 3) Does it happen in any edited file .. or only some of them? 4) Will it keep happening if you copy such affected file to another brand new empty project and edit it there? 5) Please show what you have at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Template Data Languages`

Comment: Here is the PhpStorm ticket with a similar problem -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-72288 . [This comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-72288/Unexpected-funny-file-encoding-in-completely-blank-files#focus=Comments-27-7272898.0-0) shows where the problem i s(in that project). No ideas on why it happened though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaroud to this problem until it will be fixed in PhpStorm.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/13090640028050-Weird-symbol-at-the-end-of-line-10-

> Navigate to "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style", choose
> System-dependent from the Line separator dropdown once again (even if
> it's already chosen), and click OK.

You can also check this ticket for that
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-72288